# How can i plot Y against 2 X in python using plotly or any other library

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis, plotly-python

I want plot time series data which has (2 X variables) start_timestamp and end_timestamp against (y var) interpreted_value using plotly or any other library as i want to zoom into the graph.
For every row 'interpreted_value' is constant for that (time stamp) start_timestamp to end_timestamp. Every 'end_timestamp' of previous row is start time on next row.
I am little new to this area, would be great if you could help me, Thanks in advance.

| start_timestamp | end_timestamp | interpreted_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:24.903187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.003187 | 5.96875 |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.003187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.103187 | 6.515625 |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.103187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.203187 | 7.109375 |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.203187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.303187 | 7.609375 |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.303187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.403187 | 8.21875 |

Below is the code i tried with just start_timestamp as X and interpreted_value as y:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=dff.start_timestamp,
                    y=dff.interpreted_value,
                    name = "plotly example",
                    line = dict(color = 'blue'),
                    opacity = 0.4)

layout = dict(title='plotly example',)

fig = dict(data=[trace1], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

below is the graph 1 for the reference and graph 2 is zoom in:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what visualization you are looking for, but plotly has something called a timeline graph to represent the values of an interval in time series data. I have drawn a timeline with your data. Is this the kind of visualization you are looking for?

Comment: There was no response at all, so I deleted the code I created. To see what I was trying to suggest, you can take a look at the official sample [below](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/#gantt-charts-and-timelines-with-plotlyexpress).

Comment: Thanks again for the response and the reference.